# Is there a way in IBM Speech recognition service to send URL of the file instead of the File itself

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Is there a way in IBM Speech recognition service
http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/
to send URL of the file instead of the File itself.
It is important to me since the recording that I want to send for transcribing are not stored in the same place where the code is running. I am using IBM Java SDK.

Comment: I would imagine this is extremely unlikely. Instead, you need to use the sound url to get the audio via your server and then stream it to the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a URL. You need to send the Audio file.
What you can do is register a callback so the service can send you event related to a recognition call.